# How to set td height to 0px in a table?

Tags: html, html-table

I have an HTML table containing a few rows (this is built dynamically). All `<tr>`s have one `<td>` inside.

If one `<td>` doesn’t have HTML content inside, I would like it to be invisible.

How can this be done? (Not that the HTML inside is rendered dynamically and I do not want to use `display:none` or any other property on the `<td>` or `<tr>`).

Code sample:

```
<html>
    <body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>one cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#FF0000"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>two cell</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Firefox the empty TD is invisible. However, in IE the TD takes up 1 pixel in height:

[image]

Looking with DOM Inspector I see that it takes 1 pixel:

[image]

How can I set the TD not to be visible? Any scripts I can execute inside the TD?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `display:none`?

Comment: I dont have control over the TR and the TD above. The content inside is rendered dynamically. if its empty i wouldnt want to have even 1 pixel for it.

Comment: I believe it happens due to browsers inconsistency. IE is a bitch and tables have one of the worst cross browser implementations. That is not a good combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS pseudo selector `:empty`:

```
#myDynamicTable td:empty
{
  display: none;
}
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/vKEBY/6/

And if you want to support IE<9:

```
var ieVer = getInternetExplorerVersion();
if (ieVer != -1 && ieVer < 9.0) {
    // for IE<9 support
    var dynamicTable = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
    var TDs = dynamicTable.getElementsByTagName("td");

    for (var i = 0; i < TDs.length; i++) {
        if (TDs[i].innerHTML == "") {
            TDs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

/**
  * All credits to Microsoft
  * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx#ParsingUA
  */
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
// Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
    var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null) rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
    }
    return rv;
}​
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/vKEBY/6/

Comment: Although as far as IE goes, [`:empty` only works in IE 9](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%3Aempty).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You're right, I just tested that! But you can build a solution with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for that, this is indeed nice , however we need solution for IE7 at least... any suggestion for Javascript solution?

Comment: Many thanks for your help ComFreek- I can also set the style of the parent to display:none.  What if only the content under specific TD is under my hands (or specific developer) and i want to influence only on that TD. is that possible (other then going to the parent?) anything can be done on the table or something to eliminate this IE behavior? i'm looking for solution similar to that IE9 code. Thanks! i appreciate it.

Comment: @Tal What do you mean with `parent`, the TR elements?

Comment: Developer have influence on what will be rendered inside the TD. He can, for instance, go with javascript to the parent and set it as display:none.

Comment: Are there specific IDs or classes for them?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9582/discussion-between-tal-and-comfreek)

Comment: Works only if it's the last column, otherwise cells are shifted to the left.

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery this script could become much cleaner (just a thought).

```
$('#myTable td:empty').hide();
```

Comment: Incorrect. jQuery makes all the adjustments for full cross-browser support. It will work on IE6 (if someone is unfortunate enough to use it) :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is not code called once to set up a rule, but rather would need to be called again if the table changed.