# Empty table cells have 1px height in IE7 standards mode

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

When using IE7 standards mode in IE9, empty table cells are given 1px height. This causes elements below the table to appear lower on the page than they should be. I've created a JSFiddle for this using the code below: http://jsfiddle.net/Zr7T2/3/

**Is there a way to make empty table cells have 0px height in IE7 standards mode?**

I need to solve this in HTML/CSS, not JS. Simply removing the empty cells is not an option. Thank you!

```
<!-- DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" -->
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>IE7 empty cell bug?</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                    <tr><td /></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            This text should be at the top of the page. It isn't when running in IE9 with IE7 standards mode turned on.
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Remove the comment tags in the doctype. Anything before the doctype puts IE into quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

Set the cell heights explicitly to zero:

```
td { height: 0; }
```

Comment: That does not fix the problem.

Comment: @Russ, you’re right, I must have accidentally switched mode in IE when testing. The problem also appears on IE 9 in browser mode IE 9 when document mode is set to Quirks Mode. And even setting `display: none` on empty cells fixes the problem only when the table is empty, oddly enough not when such rows are between real roles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser specific CSS like this:

```
body
{
*margin-top:-30px; /* IE 7 and below */
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific: I need to make the empty table cells have 0px height. I've updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: may be that isn't possible with HTML/CSS. please take a look at this thread: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972599/how-to-set-td-height-to-0px-in-a-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972599/how-to-set-td-height-to-0px-in-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem to. I simply put

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

But this is rather a not good prosthetic, than good solution.

Comment: This does not fix the problem